# Perhaps an easy algebra problem, but it still evades me

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation

I need help spotting a corresponding transformation

> Let $x,y$ be some variables and $$z=z(x,y)$$. We have a transformation $X(\lambda):(x,y,z)\to (x',y',z')$, such that 
>   $$x'= x\exp(a\lambda)\\
> y'= y\exp(-a\lambda)\\
> z'= z\exp(-3a\lambda)$$
>   where $a$ is a constant.
>   Let $$w\equiv z^2-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
>   What transformation $X'(\lambda)$ such that $X'$ transforms $(x,y,w)\to (F_x(x,y,w),F_y(x,y,w), F_w(x,y,w))$ to the corresponding quantities given by $X(\lambda)$ where $F_i$ are functions of $x,y,w$?
>
> By ***corresponding*** I just mean that the "values/expressions" of $$X'(x),X'(y),X'(w)$$ are equal to $$X(x),X(y),X\left(z^2-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)$$ respectively. Note though that $X'(x),X'(y),X'(w)$ are functions of $x,y,w$

I presume the action of $X'(\lambda)$ on $x,y$ remains the same. But what about that on $w$?

We have $$w'= z'^2-\frac{\partial z'}{\partial x'}\\
= z^2\exp(-6a\lambda)-\exp(-4a\lambda)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
But how can I express this in terms of $x,y,w$?

Advanced thanks for any help!

Comment: The problem is not phrased clearly enough to solve.

Comment: @dfeuer: What would you like clarified? :)

Comment: To begin with, you use $\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}$, but you never said anywhere that $z$ was to be considered a function of anything in particular. Did you mean that $z$ is to be a function of $x$ and $y$? And then "corresponding quantities" is a bit unclear too. Corresponding how?

Comment: I don't mean to be a jerk or anything, but sometimes just doing the grunt work of expressing the problem in a tediously precise fashion will begin to lead to a solution.

Comment: @dfeuer: No worries. Your point is valid. :) I have edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: A small suggestion: come up with a name for the function corresponding to $z$.  That is, let $z = g(x,y)$ or some such. That should help you come up with a more sensible expression for $w'$. May I ask why this is tagged algebra-precalculus?

Comment: Why is $w' = z'^2- \frac{\partial z'}{\partial x'}$? What is the difference between $z$ and $w$ that will lead $X$ to act differently, because they are both functions of x and y. With this information I would think that $X'=X$ $\dots$